# PHPUnit setup in Batch File

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, cmd, phpunit

I am not preferring using PEAR method, so I decided to use another way, However, I still cannot make a perfect .bat file to run in two situations.

I downloaded the phpunit.phar and the path I had added into PATH => `C:\dev`
e.g `C:\dev\phpunit.phar`

I also create a `phpunit.bat` file inside `C:\dev\phpunit.bat`, this allow me to run `phpunit` in any place.

This is the content of the `phpunit.bat`

```
@echo off
php c:\dev\phpunit.phar
```

I have run perfectly result when I am using the guard-phpunit. However, the problem is when I want to pass an argument / parameter to the phpunit it does not work.

E.g I got a testing file in `C:\testing\CalculatorTest.php`
When I run

```
C:\testing>phpunit C:\testing\CalculatorTest.php
```

or

```
C:\testing>phpunit CalculatorTest.php
```

It only output like `php phpunit.phar`, it does not take the argument.

It only work when I enter the command like this

```
C:\testing>php c:\dev\phpunit.phar CalculatorTest.php
```

I try to edit the phpunit.bat file to make it like below:

```
@echo off
set arg1=%1

:start
if "%1"=="" (goto :main)
REM without any argument
php C:\dev\phpunit.phar
goto :end

:main
php C:\dev\phpunit.phar %arg1%
:end
```

The above code will work in `C:\testing>php c:\dev\phpunit.phar CalculatorTest.php`, but when run in guard-phpunit it will keep prompting **option --include-path requires an argument** error.

Anyone know how to fix the .bat so it able to run in both situation?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created phpunit.bat file in same directory of the phpunit are instaled, for example `B:\libs`, containing:

```
@ECHO OFF
php "%~dp0phpunit.phar" %*
```

and in the windows PATH variable I added `;B:\libs`:

1. Hold <kbd>Win</kbd> and press <kbd>Pause</kbd>.
2. Click Advanced System Settings.
3. Click Environment Variables.
4. Append `;B:\libs` to the `Path` variable.
5. Restart Command Prompt.

After restart the terminal PHPunit works:

```
PS C:\Users\joridos> phpunit.bat --version
PHPUnit 4.1.3 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for `phpunit.bat`:

```
@echo off
php c:\dev\phpunit.phar %*
```

`%*` is replaced on execution by whatever was passed to `phpunit.bat` which means nothing if nothing was passed to `phpunit.bat`, or first + second + third + ... arguments exactly as specified on calling `phpunit.bat`.